# Is there an aftermarket USB->DockConnector cable that works with an iPhone 4 + bumper case?

Tags: iphone, accessories, hardware-recommendation

I'm looking for a third-party (i.e., cheaper) alternative to the [Apple Dock Connector to USB Cable](http://store.apple.com/us/product/MA591G/A) that is compatible with an iPhone 4 **w/ bumper case**. I've tried a few third-party cables and none of them are able to connect properly with the bumper case installed on the phone.

Also, I'd prefer it if the dock connector end of the cable *doesn't* have the press-to-disconnect buttons.

Comment: Any particular reason why you don't want the first-party cable?

Comment: Sorry, should have clarified that -- would prefer not spending $20 on the official cable, when I've been able to get compatible aftermarket cables for <$4 in the past (pre-iPhone4).

Comment: Note that this problem also occurs with some car-connection kits and stereo systems, where replacement with official Apple cable is not an easy option.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this'll work: http://cablejive.com/istubz

EDIT:
Whoops, maybe not. The 1st party cables are a precision molded plastic that is thinner than the 3rd-party clones as detailed in this video @ 3:40 -

http://youtube.com/watch?v=XpmLvY2XNPg

Answer (score 1):

I just spent 10 minutes in the garage with my Dremel tool, taking off a couple of MM off the plastic around the top of the after-market plugs.  Now they fit fine into the iPhone 4 Bumbper case.  Problem solved.

Comment: Alternatively, you could probably shave a few mm off of the inside of the bumper.  But I'd rather mutilate the cables than the bumper.